# Scope doesn't refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i have a problem with an http.get.

**Index.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements">
<p>{{element.elementText}}</p>
</div>
```

**app.js**

I have two controllers. First one initialize **$scope.elements** with a json and works:

```
$http.get('someUrl')
.success(function (response) {
 $scope.elements = response;
})
```

Seconde one update **$scope.elements** with a another json when a scope function is called by ng-click:

```
$scope.updateScope = function () {
$http.get('someOtherUrl')
.then(function (response) {
 $scope.elements = response.data;
});
```

But when i call updateScope nothing appens. I try use .success but nothing. I try using $scope.$apply after assign response to $scope.elements but it generates an error (Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest).

**UPDATE - 
If I reload page ng-repeat on scope element works correctly.**
So $scope.elements contains right values but ng-repeat doesn't update itself.
Sorry for my english...

Could you help me please?

Comment: Have you verified what the `response` looks like? Does it look just like the previous response? Is there a response at all?

Comment: Yes Michael Perrenoud. It contains new values.

Comment: Have you verified it should be set directly to the response? My point is that the digest is already running so it's not Angular missing the update. There's likely something *different* about the second response.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed you mentioned you have **two different controllers**; do you truly mean **controllers** or do you just mean a method off the scope of the **single controller** that updates the data?

Comment: No, i have two controllers and $scope.elements is initialized in .run(function ($rootScope) { $rootscope.elements = ''; });

Comment: @EthanHunt Can you provide the codes of your two controllers?

Comment: Code is very large, but the interesting point is similar to posted code.

Comment: So first off, you really should be putting that shared data in a service. But secondly, you're not setting `$rootScope` here in the second controller, you're setting `$scope`; those are two different objects. If you want `$rootScope` updated then you need to update it.

Comment: Excuse me Micheal, but why when i reload page $scope.elements contains elements setted by second controller? Thanks very much for your help

Comment: I can't answer that, there's too much going on with your code that we can't interpret. I mean it wasn't even clear that there were *two distinct controllers* when looking at this code. However, if you want to share data you need to put it into a service that can be injected. That service can house a local variable that is the data; don't use root scope.

Answer (score 1):

`.then(function (response) {` and `.success(function (response) {` gets **different objects** in their callbacks. In the first case you get the response's data directly, in second it will be wrapped in an object (that has also other properties - like `status`, `config`, `statusText`, and so on).

If you use `.then` your response's body will be in `sth.data`, not in `sth`. So in your case:

```
$scope.updateScope = function () {
$http.get('someOtherUrl').then(function (response) {
    $scope.elements = response.data;
});
```

Comment: Yes Tomek. Sorry. I'll edit my answer. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular.merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge)

```
angular.merge(object1, object2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To share data you want to use a service, not root scope. Consider an example like this:

## HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controller1 as vm">
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.dataService.data" />{{vm.dataService.data}}</div>
    <div ng-controller="controller2 as vm">
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.dataService.data" />{{vm.dataService.data}}</div>
</div>
```

## JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('DataService', function () {
    var data;
    return {
        data: 'Hello, World!'
    };
});

app.controller('controller1', function (DataService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dataService = DataService;
});

app.controller('controller2', function (DataService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dataService = DataService;
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3n3ae24/) that runs that code.

Comment: Thanks Micheal. I understood it. But my problem is that ng-repeat doesn't update itself with right values setted in second controller. If i reload page it works.

Answer (score -1):

you can try following code.(you need to include $timeout)

```
$scope.updateScope = function () {
    $http.get('someOtherUrl')
    .then(function (response) {
    $scope.elements = response;
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply();
    });
});
```

Comment: No, this is not necessary. There is something different about the second response.